# how to pass location and image in prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a table view which have custom cell with - image , mapview , some text,sometext - all the data are saved in coredata

when tapped on cell it will navigate to detail view .
In that i need to show image , mapview , sometext .
I am unable to pass the location(map coordinates) and image to detailed view .
how to do?

i have stored latitude , longitude , latitudeDelta , longitudeDelata in core data - these needs to be transferred to next view

Comment: am not getting how to pass the latitude and longitude value

Comment: do the answers you have been given fix your problem?  Let us know if it's still not working, or choose one of the answers as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your destination controller is defined as  `DisplayDetailViewController` then you need to add the variables you want to pass to it like this

```
class DisplayDetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    var latitude : Double?
    var longitude  : Double?
    var latitudeDelta  : Double?
    var longitudeDelata : Double?

    // everything else in this class
}
```

here's what you need in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, where you have defined the segue as `MyShowDetailSegue`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyShowDetailSegue", sender: self)
}
```

finally, you prepare for the segue in the `prepareForSegue` method - showing here how you would do that for a number of different transitions - take out the checks if there's only the one

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    switch segue.identifier!
    {
    case "MyShowDetailSegue":
        let destinationController : DisplayDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DisplayDetailViewController

        destinationController.delegate = self // you will need this if you're using a delegate to make updates back in the original controller

        destinationController.latitude = latitude
        destinationController.longitude = longitude
        destinationController.latitudeDelta = latitudeDelta
        destinationController.longitudeDelta = longitudeDelta

    case "MyOtherSegue":
        //  do other stuff
        destinationController.delegate = self

    case "MyOtherOtherSegue":
        //  do other stuff
        destinationController.delegate = self

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue` has a `segue` argument, and you can access the view controller of the detail view with `segue.destinationViewController` (make sure to force downcast it using `as!`). Then you can directly set its properties.

Answer (score 0):

create properties in your destinationViewController ans set value in prepareForSegue as given below

```
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "pushText"{
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PublishVC
        destinationVC.noteID = "a"

    }
}
```